# python passing list between functions

Tags: python, list, parameter-passing

I am struggling to pass a list (`holder`, which contains `[0,0]`) to another function. I want `check_neighbours` to pick up the list and then do some further processing. I think I am passing it correctly in `main()` but I am not sure what I must do to get the list to simply display its contents when called upon inside `check_neighbours`. I have tried a `=` holder but I received the error:

> global name "holder" is not defined

I believe I must put `holder = #something` here but I cannot figure out what.

```
 def create_matrix(file):
    with open('network.txt') as f:
        Alist = []
        for line in f:
            part = []
            for x in line.split(','):
                part.append(int(x))
            Alist.append(part)
    return Alist

def start_node(Alist):
        i=0
        j=0
        #point node to pos [0][0] of Alist
        node = Alist[i][j]
        #create a list to hold co-ordinates
        holder = []
        holder.append(i)
        holder.append(j)
        print holder

        return node, holder

#test neighbours to see if they can be used
def check_neighbours(node, Alist):
        holder = #something 



#code begins here
def main():
        file = ("F:/media/KINGSTON/Networking/network.txt")
        Alist = create_matrix(file)
        node = start_node(Alist)
        holder = check_neighbours(node, Alist)
main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end of `start_node`, you do this:

```
return node, holder
```

… but when you call it, you do this:

```
node = start_node(Alist)
```

That means your local `node` variable ends up as a tuple of `node, holder`. You don't want that. You want this:

```
node, holder = start_node(Alist)
```

Meanwhile, you say "I think I am passing it correctly in the main() function", but you're *not* passing it at all in the `main` function:

```
holder = check_neighbours(node, Alist)
```

There's no way for `check_neighbours` to get `holder` here, because you're not giving it `holder` here.

Plus, when you defined `check_neighbours`, you did this:

```
def check_neighbours(node, Alist):
    holder = #something
```

This doesn't take a `holder` parameter, it defines a new local variable named `holder`. So, change those two lines to:

```
def check_neighbours(node, Alist, holder):
```

And call it with:

```
holder = check_neighbours(node, Alist, holder)
```

Also, note that you're assigning the result of `check_neighbors` back to the `holder` variable, replacing whatever you passed in. Often, that's a perfectly reasonable thing to do (think `my_name = my_name.replace('Joseph', 'Joe')`), but make sure it really is what you want (and, of course, make sure that `check_neighbors` ends by doing a `return holder`, or returning some other appropriate value).

Finally, as I said in your other question: If you keep using the same name for your parameters and the values you pass in, you're going to keep confusing yourself like this. If you used different names, it would be much easier for you to see what you're missing. Even something as simple as a prefix on each one:

```
def main():
    file = ("F:/media/KINGSTON/Networking/network.txt")
    my_list = create_matrix(file)
    my_node, my_holder = start_node(my_list)
    my_new_holder = check_neighbours(my_node, my_list, my_holder)
```

Comment: thank you again, I am making quite a few assumptions about how variable passing works but I appreciate your help greatly

Comment: @bigl: Here's the simple rule of thumb: Variable passing is always completely explicit. If you have `def foo(x, y, z):`, and it ends with `return v, w`, you will always need to call it with 3 values, and store the result in 2, like `a, b = foo(c, d, e)`. (This rule of thumb is modified in more complicated cases, like classes with methods, global variables, etc., but ignore those for now.)

Comment: thank you for that, very useful information. everything is working great now.